# Make two timers work and end when they are supposed to?

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a timer that I can create an instance of an run. I have created this at the end of this code. What I want to be able to do is be able to start each timer and have them run at the same time but when one finishes the other should continue.

This code works but the timers both keep going. How would I change it so that when one timer ends that it doesn't reset and then the second timer ends then everything stops.

Maybe I should be using a thread? Not sure on this one? Maybe each timer can be linked to a thread.

Code (Program):

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DDHTypeCasting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnoyingBeep y1 = new AnnoyingBeep(5,"Timer 1");
        AnnoyingBeep y2 = new AnnoyingBeep(10,"Timer 2");
            System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}

class AnnoyingBeep {
    Timer timer;

    public AnnoyingBeep() { }

    public AnnoyingBeep(int a, String s) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(a,s),a,1*1000); //delay
    }
}

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    Toolkit toolkit;
    int numWarningBeeps = 0;
    String myString = null;

    RemindTask(int a, String s) {
        numWarningBeeps = a;
        myString = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (numWarningBeeps > 0) {
            System.out.format("Beep!%n " + myString);
            numWarningBeeps--;
        } else {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n " + myString);
           // System.exit(0);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah you should use thread for back ground operations
if anything related to foreground then u can use AsyncTask and from asynctask you can start another thread that can be handler or Thread.
try this , hope this works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to implement `Runnable` interface and use it like `Thread`:

```
public class ThreadTimer extends Timer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {

    }
}
```